# setInterval cleared without a var

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I am using node.js to read a bunch of directories, as such async is really hurting me to keep track of it all.

I am using a setInterval to track and report progress, however being in a loop I cannot give it a variable name without some sort of crazy object organizing.

So is it possible to just clear the interval inside of the interval when a statement is met?

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(list.length==count){
    clearInterval(self)
  }
},50);
```

Basically "count" is a tally that i increment as i scan the directories and list.length is the actual amount of items in the directory. Because the loop will complete before the directories are scanned I have to keep this outside of the actual loop.

I remember there was a way to call the callee in javascript, but even with a bit of Google I can't seem to find if its possible.

So basically I want to clear the interval without setting the interval through a variable.

Comment: Have you considered using `async` in parallel mode to track all your various iterations? You can let it do the work and sync up once all threads are complete.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill to set up, that and I don't have a clue what your talking about :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
(function(){
    var x = setInterval(function(){
        //some if
        clearInterval(x);
    }, 50);
})();
```

You can scope your interval variable to the inner function.

Comment: Seeing this pulled the haze over my mind, yeah this should work!